# Pinch zoom for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created my custom view and I want to apply pinch zoom for my custom view. How to do that?

Answer (score 93):

This article on the Android Developers Blog covers this topic very well (scroll down to the section on **GestureDetectors**):

[Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

If you just want to implement pinch-to-zoom, there's only a few lines of code you'll need:

```
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public MyCustomView(Context mContext){
    //...
    //Your view code
    //...
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    //...
    //Your onDraw() code
    //...
    canvas.restore();
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

The rest of the article deals with handling other gestures but rather than using their implementation, you can use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) just like ScaleGestureDetector is used in the code above.

Comment: I am done with this but how can I drag or scroll  the zoomed view

Comment: @sillyMistaker about the pan it is very well explained in the post's link. It's too much content for a comment, but still it follows pretty easy logic.

Comment: how to implement this on listview?

Comment: Never thought that it would be this easy to implement. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Put your view inside `ZoomView`.

Custom view available here https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view it's easy, free and so much fun!

Comment: Any documentation to go along with that?

Comment: nice example, but it causes much invalidate calls.

Comment: Unfortunately the project doesn't appear to have been active for the last 6 months.  I submitted a pull request to fix an obvious bug 15 days ago, but I did not get any response.

Comment: did you get it how to use it?

Comment: How can I zoom surface view with zoomView , is this is not supporting with this class

Comment: Like this you can add one view to another

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.goaps.ZoomView
    android:id="@+id/customviewalpha"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    </com.goaps.ZoomView>

Comment: This GitHub repository is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

This library allows you to apply zooming and panning to custom views.  It worked for my needs:

https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout

Comment: Amazing, it helped me a lot; I was struggling with zooming my custom imageView that had drawings on top of it's canvas. This library really solved the issue for me.  Thank you for mentioning it!

Answer (score -2):

use this :

> Implementation of ImageView for Android that supports zooming, by various touch gestures.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Photoview works fine only on ImageView, but didn't get the View, which is extended by another class. How to work with CustomView please.?