# Zooming and Panning of view in android

Tags: android, view, zooming, panning

Hi friends
I am creating one app where i put two views. first is imageview and the other one is my customeview.

i am drawing image on my custom view. my custom view code is as follow

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "DrawView";
    Painter painter = new Painter();
    PathStack pathStack;
    private DrawApplication drawApplication;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        drawApplication=(DrawApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
        pathStack=drawApplication.getPainter().getPathStack();
        painter=drawApplication.getPainter();
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float scaleFactor=drawApplication.getScaleFactor();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,(float)getWidth()/2,(float)getHeight()/2);
        List<DrawingPath> currentStack=pathStack.getCurrentStack();

        for (DrawingPath drawPath : currentStack) {
            drawPath.draw(canvas, painter);

        }

    }
}
```

many things clear from code like storing path on drawapplication etc.

now we have decided to provide zooming and panning to this view. and my drawing should also be zoomed accordingly along with imageview which in back.

also i should be able to draw correctly.

I tried canvas scaling but that is worst, because after scaling i am not able to draw to the touched point and also less drawing to the screen resulting in more drawing to the view.

drawing on widget is also very lengthy task results in performance slow down.
plz provide any way.

and also i am using api level 10.

**Edit1**

Well friends. i got one idea. 
i have to draw path on different zoom level. so if we can calculate path ratio in different zoom level than it will solve my problem. plz provide help accordingly

**Edit2**

if we will be able to scale path then it can solve my problem

**Edit3**

i think if we draw it on bitmap than i can achieve my goal, but my problem is resizing bitmap and providing scrolling to bitmap on different zoom level

Comment: For panning, you can use View's framework for scrolling. If you also want smooth scrolling I've answered that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951142/smooth-scrolling-in-android/4951681#4951681) (if you don't, you can just return true in `onDown()` and leave out the `mScroller`/`onFling()` code). For the zoom, I'm sorry but I did that only with `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions on SO:

- [android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)
- [Pinch zoom for custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view)

Can be done on Honeycomb (API lvl 11) but not properly before.

Comment: pinching is not my issue, but i don't want to create custom views. i want to provide zooming and panning to android standard view

Comment: Whether you want to do it by pinching or by a click on a button, the answer is the same. You cannot do it on API < 11.

Comment: i just edited my question, could we get solution through this way

Comment: hi have you reviewed my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a normal view can be zoomed. You could capture the touch events and scale the view widgets correspondingly.

Comment: What I essentially meant, MarvinLabs has pointed to in detail... That's probably the only way to go.

Comment: i just edited my question, could we get solution through this way

Comment: You will need to share some code, and be more specific. Suggest you take a simple shape and try it out.