# zooming listview in android

Tags: android, listview, zooming, pinchzoom

I want to zoom in my listview. My listview contains textviews. I want to be able to zoom the listview, so that items in the listview can be read easily.

Please guide me about that. I am a new android developer.

Comment: add andriod tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around where you could put text in WebView which is easily zoomable
The straight forward way would be quite hard to implement you could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view)