# Drag listview on zoom

Tags: android, listview, pinchzoom

I am able to zoom custom listview, by using this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html)

This listview is in viewpager.

My problem is, when a view is zoomed, I dont know how to drag(by drag i mean move ListView to end - from left to right as well as from top to bottom vice-versa) it to see complete list.
Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: yes this is possible. please refer to my answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196503/pinch-zoom-on-a-listview/25845655#25845655