# Zoom Entire Screen Android

Tags: android

Recently, I have been working on an app that requires that the entire screen be zoomed in and out by pinch zoom. In the past I have worked with zoomed singular ImageViews but I am a bit stumped on how to zoom everything on a screen.

For example, if a user where to pinch zoom in the center of the screen everything would stay relatively the same size of each other but it would give the appearance that the screen was zooming in.

Comment: Are you want to increase the size of the text on `zoom in` then you can change the font size of `textView` at run time.

Comment: It has to be an on entire view really. So that for example, if you zoomed into the top left quarter then the top-left quarter of the screen would now fill the screen.

Comment: Zoom should be implemented on the view which fills the entire screen and add all the UI elements inside that view.

Comment: Pinch to Zoom on a Custom View , Take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view

Comment: Oh right, so if I have a (for example) relative layout and then zoom that every view inside it will also zoom? Thats handy.