# ListView pinch-to-zoom possible?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, gesture, pinchzoom

I'm trying to implement pinch-to-zoom on a ListView which contains small pieces of code. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I suspect it may be not possible to implement multitouch zoom on a ListView. I currently have used this implementation:
http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c16ed3b4-b422-43ba-b595-ee8e21dd1854

My target is Android 2.2+.
Does anyone have an example of pinch-to-zoom to zoom in and out on the text?
Or is it just not possible to do it effectively on a ListView?

I would include my code, but it's similar to that in the above example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305303/1393623) for implementing pinch-to-zoom on any custom view.

And to make sure that the ListView responds to all the events and not only the pinch gesture, override **`onTouchEvent()`** in the following way to let the `ScaleGestureDetector` detect/handle all the events.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    myScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```