# PinchZoom and Drag - Android Studio

Tags: android, drag, pinchzoom, pan

I have a layout created in android studio but the views can't fit in the screen. I want to implement pinch zoom and drag on the layout, but i don't have any idea on how to implement pinch zoom and drag. I need to finish this project for my thesis project, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale gestures for this like :

[Pinch zoom for custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view)

[android pinch zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375817/android-pinch-zoom)

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview