# How do I enable pinch to zoom inside a graph?

Tags: java, android, zooming, pinch

I have a `graph API` that I am using to display data. Now, I wish to enable `pinch` to zoom from within the graph such that the user can zoom into the graph. I tried to implement with ScaleGestureDetector using the method described in [Pinch zoom for custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view). But the problem I am getting is:

1. When I try to **invalidate()** it says `Cannot resolve method`
2. In the `onDraw` method, when I code `super.onDraw(canvas);` it says `cannot resolve method onDraw`.

I am new to Android development, so excuse me if the question is too basic. I have been read the Android Developers blog on *Multitouch* and I have used the stackoverflow link mentioned above; still no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

The graph API I used is from [here](https://github.com/Steven-Luo/android-bezier-curve-chart).