# Android: Zooming with two views

Tags: java, android, xml, view, zooming

in my android app I have an ImageView and on top of it I put a custom view, which shows some rectangles. Now I want to zoom into the image by pinching two fingers. Usually that's not a problem but I want the custom View to be zoomed with the same scale factor as the image. I don't have a clue, how to do this. Can someone help me please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom `ImageView` provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out/54474455#54474455) which supports zoom with pinching, and to get the scale value to be applied your custom view, you need to create a listener with a callback that you can call typically from the `onScale()` method of the `ScaleListener` like below

```
interface OnScaleListener {
    public onScaleChange(float scaleFactor);
}

OnScaleListener mOnScaleListener;

setScaleListener(OnScaleListener listener) {
    this.mOnScaleListener = listener;
}
```

And then trigger this callback with the value of the `mScaleFactor` which reflects how much is the image is zoomed in/out. so you can create an instance of the onScaleListener interface within this class, and trigger its callback `onScaleChange()`

Here is the inner class of the [custom ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out/54474455#54474455) that handles the pinch zoom.

```
    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            mOnScaleListener.onScaleChange(mScaleFactor);

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And then make your activity or your other custom view implements the `OnScaleListener` interface to get the scale value.

Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216658/pinch-zoom-for-custom-view) to zoom-in custom views.